# MYSQL INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql

I wrote a MySQL query for exporting data into text file.

Query runs successfully but result did not match my expectations.

I want to result without spacing between columns.

```
select 
    sample_export_record1_2013.*, 
    sample_export_record2_2013.* 
from 
    sample_export_record1_2013 
inner join
    sample_export_record2_2013 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Windows/temp/a20.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "" 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
STARTING BY '0'
```

Currently output is generated by this query like this :

```
01 181 2 0 P 5701 13.01.A.01 9664 0 94003048 94002596 0 3 20130101 20130106 000000001223 20130106 \N \N \N 2 1 258972658 9664 426407407 75 20050917 1 1 Reijtest \N 2 Reijtest \N o 1 2402LS \N 130 \N NL \N \N \N
```

I want the output without space between columns - just look like

```
0118120P570113.01.A.0196640940030489400259603201301012013010600000000122320130106\N\N\N212589726589664426407407752005091711 Reijtest\N2Reijtest\No12402LS\N130\NNL\N\N\N
```

Comment: Do you have spaces in one column or do you want to merge multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

Just use concat, `SELECT CONCAT(rec1, rec2,rec3) as 'results' FROM...`

Comment: can i used it for two table also ?

Comment: Sorry mistake there, `CONCAT (rec1, '.', rec2)` etc, sure in what instance? All the concat does is concatenate the fields into one field. So if you can normally select from 2 tables in one select you can concat the selected results

Comment: unless you want something like this `SELECT CONCAT((SELECT CONCAT(tbl1.rec1, ".", tb1.rec2), ".", CONCAT(tbl2.rec1, ".", tb2.rec2)) AS 'all_results'` So two sub queries all doing their own concatenations with an outer SELECT connecting it

Comment: Thanks ,
Hope it will help me .